# Perl Mojolicious, what's the correct way to render a response from a Promise?

Tags: rest, perl, promise, concurrency, mojolicious

In Mojolicious, what's the correct way to render a response from a Promise? In my code below, I get:

```
[2023-04-12] [trace] Template "example/search.html.ep" not found
[2023-04-12] [trace] Nothing has been rendered, expecting delayed response
```

1. Why is it looking for `example/search.html.ep`? I didn't ask for it.
2. I am rendering content... Mojo couldn't wait?

My sample app has 3 files:

#### 1. `script/my_app`

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Mojo::File qw(curfile);
use lib curfile->dirname->sibling('lib')->to_string;
use Mojolicious::Commands;

Mojolicious::Commands->start_app('MyApp');
```

#### 2. `lib/MyApp.pm`

```perl
package MyApp;
use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious', -signatures;

sub startup ($self) {
    $self->secrets('s3cret');
    my $r = $self->routes;
    $r->get('/')->to('Example#index');
    $r->post('/')->to('Example#search');
}

1;
```

#### 3. `lib/MyApp/Controller/Example.pm`

```perl
package MyApp::Controller::Example;
use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious::Controller', -signatures;

sub index ($self)
{
    return $self->render(inline => '<html><body><form method="post"><textarea name="numbers" maxlength="11">123</textarea><button type="submit">Go</button></form></body></html>');
}

sub search ($self)
{
    my $v = $self->validation;
    $v->required("numbers");
    return $self->render(text=>"Validation Error") if $v->has_error;
    my $numbers = $v->param("numbers");
    my @numbers = split(/\r?\n/, $numbers);

    Mojo::Promise
    ->map(
    {concurrency => 2},
    sub {
        $self->ua->get_p("https://httpbin.org/delay/1?q=$_" => {'api-key'=>'shhh'});
    }, @numbers)
    ->then(
    sub{
        my @results = @_;
        my @json = map { $_->[0]->res->json } @results;
        return $self->render(json => \@json);
    })
    ->catch(
    sub {
        my $err = shift;
        return $self->render(text => $err);
    })
    ->wait;
    #return $self->render(text => "This shall result is 'Unhandled rejected promise: A response has already been rendered'");
}

1;
```

To run the app, I do:

```bash
morbo script/my_app
```

then navigate to [`http://localhost:3000`](http://localhost:3000) and post the form. Multiple lines will result in concurrent calls.

Comment: Have you tried using `render_later` instead of `render` on the `->then` sub?

Comment: `wait()` is documented to be a noop if you have your ioloop running already. https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Promise#ioloop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a [`render_later`](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojolicious/Controller#render_later) before invoking the Promise:

```
$self->render_later();

Mojo::Promise
  ->map(
    {concurrency => 2},
...
```

Without it, when the function `search` exits, Mojolicious will by default render the associated template (`example/search.html.ep`), and fail because this template doesn't exist (see [Automatic rendering](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojolicious/Guides/Rendering#Automatic-rendering) in Mojolicious::Guide::Rendering). The `render_later` disables this automatic rendering, basically telling Mojolicious "keep the connection open, I'll render something later".

---

Your confusion may come from the use of [`wait`](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojo/Promise#wait), which doesn't really "wait" in this context. If you add a print before and after the whole promise thing:

```
say "Before";
Mojo::Promise->map(...);
say "After";
```

Then the log will be:

```
[2023-04-13 09:23:08.78601] [1201283] [trace] [rR7TxcCsrygT] POST "/"
[2023-04-13 09:23:08.78692] [1201283] [trace] [rR7TxcCsrygT] Routing to controller "MyApp::Controller::Example" and action "search"
Before
After
[2023-04-13 09:23:08.78953] [1201283] [trace] [rR7TxcCsrygT] Template "example/search.html.ep" not found
...
```

Which does show that the `wait` didn't really wait (if you're not convinced, you can even add prints in the `then` and `catch`: they'll be printed after `After`).

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojo/Promise#wait) of `wait`, it says:

> Start "ioloop" and stop it again once the promise has been fulfilled or rejected, does nothing when "ioloop" is already running.

Here, since you are running a server, the IOLoop is always running, so `wait` does nothing. This is actually desirable: if `wait` were to actually wait, then there would be no point in using a Promise.
On the other hand, when you use Mojo::Promise on its own (ie, not in a Mojolicious server), you might need to manually run the IOLoop with `wait` in order to not exit your script before your promise is finished.